# CodeSign Verification Failed - Adobe Flash AIR iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flash, air, codesign

There are a lot of topics about this, but I've been searching and trying for two straight days now and I can't find an solution. The terminal doesn't give me any error (codesign -vvvv):

```
/Users/Tim/Documents/appNaam/Payload/Naam.app: valid on disk
/Users/Tim/Documents/appNaam/Payload/Naam.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

If I use codesign -dvvvv, I can see that the application is signed.

```
Identifier=com.Company.App
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv7)
CodeDirectory v=20001 size=55034 flags=0x0(none) hashes=2743+5 location=embedded
CDHash=e7e6edf4cbcfab6e7d482eccbe8b25314d7dddb3
Signature size=4250
Authority=iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=16 jan 2012 20:10:51
Info.plist entries=33
Sealed Resources rules=5 files=27
Internal requirements count=0 size=12
```

I've tried deleting certificates, provisions over and over. I've tried to export only the key, only the certificate and both of them. I extract the .ipa and compress it into an zip. I've tried everything but it doesn't seem to work.

Please help me! 
Thanks in advanced,
Tim

Comment: Want to tell us what command you're running and what the error is?

Comment: The error is when I'm uploading the app with the application loader, I get  "Codesign Verification failed..".

Comment: Could you please describe me more exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it after days of hard thinking and trying stuff out.
It was an answer I haven't found anywhere else in topics. When you request an certificate, in the namefield it sets an standard name. This wasn't my full name, which my developers account was registered with. I've set this straight and finally everything worked!